# Stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program in python that converts a decimal number into it's hexadecimal equivalent. When I run the program, it gives me the correct conversion, but it runs on an infinite loop. I'm not sure where exactly the infinite loop is occurring. This is my code:

```
def remainderToHex(remainder):
    if remainder <= 9:
        remainder = str (remainder)
    elif remainder == 10:
        remainder = "A"
    elif remainder == 11:
        remainder = "B"
    elif remainder == 12:
        remainder = "C"
    elif remainder == 13:
        remainder = "D"
    elif remainder == 14:
        remainder = "E"
    elif remainder == 15:
        remainder = "F"
    return remainder

def decToHex(decNum):
    hexNum = ""
    quotient = decNum
    divNum=16
    if quotient == 0:
        hexNum = 0
    while quotient > 0:
        remainder = quotient % divNum
        convertedHex= remainderToHex(remainder)
        quotient = int (quotient / divNum)
        hexNum = convertedHex + hexNum 
    return hexNum

def main():
    decNum=int(raw_input("Please enter a non negative number OR enter -1 to quit: "))
    while decNum >= -1:
        hexNumber = decToHex(decNum)
        print decNum, "convered to hex is: ", hexNumber
    print "Thank you"
```

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, there is a built-in function `hex()` that does just what you want,

Comment: ... And even if you don't want to use `hex()` for some reason, that routine is a bit ugly. Even `return "0123456789ABCDEF"[remainder]` would be preferable...

Comment: I'm not supposed to use any built in functions for this code!

Answer (score 8):

You are doing `while decNum >= -1`.  Assuming that the user does not enter -1 right off the bat, then `decNum` will *never* become less than -1, and the while loop will never end.  Instead, use an if statement.  If the user enters -1, end the procedure, else do your conversion.

As has been pointed out, the `>=` should be `>`

Comment: Or initialize `decNum` to 0 and put the `raw_input` line inside the while loop.

Comment: Absolutely, though you would need to assign `decNum` prior to the while loop to avoid a name error.  As I see you just accounted for!

Comment: Yeah, Also I guess >=-1 is supposed to be >-1.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you wanted to do was:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":    
    decNum = 0
    while decNum > -1:
        decNum=int(raw_input("Please enter a non negative number OR enter -1 to quit: "))
        hexNumber = decToHex(decNum)
        print decNum, "convered to hex is: ", hexNumber
    print "Thank you"
```

However, you can also just use a simple if statement, might be the better way unless you're not gonna do more stuff inside the loop itself. Also keep in mind that with `>= -1` you will keep looping even in case of -1.

Comment: This did the trick!! I should have initialized decNum before making the while loop. Thanks so much! And thank you to everyone else who answered.

Answer (score 1):

The infinite loop is occurring because `decNum` always stays equal to whatever value the user inputs. So the condition for the while loop is always true.

Since there are no repeated calculations required in the main function, swap the `while` with an `if`, which is the correct statement here since you are making a choice to quit if user enters `-1`. A `while` loop would be required if your program asked for multiple values from user to be converted into hex. If that is the case, move the `decNum` assignment statement into the loop as well. This would ask for a new value for `decNum` every time the last input number has been converted to hex. If a user enters `-1` in any iteration, the loop condition will fail and the program will move out of it.

However your condition is also incorrect if you need to quit if user enters `-1`. It could be `if decNum > -1` or `while decNum != -1`, whichever is the case.

Answer (score -1):

Well, everyone else has beaten me to the answer before I could finish typing it, so I'll delete it, and add the only other bit of wisdom that I see necessary: If you're learning Python, you should be learning with Python 3.x, not Python 2.x.

I not looking to start any flame wars, but Python 2.x is a dead branch, and the future is 3.x

It's quite easy to move between 2.x and 3.x, but why learn the old unless you need to?

(and yes, I'm aware of the large 2.x code base still out there)

Comment: While this may be a true observation, it doesn't even pretend to answer the question, so it should be a comment instead...

Comment: I can only add comments to my own messages, not to other comments. Interesting that everyone forgets this on SO... and the down-votes just keep me under a 50 rep to perpetuate this problem. Lost another 2 points of rep for trying to add useful commentary to a question. :-)

Comment: Python 2 isn't "a dead branch" at all. 2.7.9 was released last month.

Comment: Check the comments from the Python team on Python.org - it's dead as the dodo. You'll only see patches for problems, or additions of libs that make porting to 3.x easier.  No new development will occur in 2.x https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0404/